# Stellar Ignition and Neutrino Energy

Tags: astrophysics, fusion, stellar-physics

My question has to do with the following two pieces of information:

1. When Fusion Ignites and a star is born, according to the Proton-Proton Chain, a positron and a neutrino are released when one proton undergoes beta+ decay and becomes a neutron.
2. "The mass of an atomic nucleus is less than the sum of the individual masses of the free constituent protons and neutrons (according to Einstein's equation E=mc2) and this 'missing mass' is known as the mass defect, and represents the energy that was released when the nucleus was formed." https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Mass_defect

My question is this: is the excess energy of the mass defect added to the positron and neutrino?

My guess is yes, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the energy is transferred to the kinetic energy of the particles that are produced.

Comment: That is what I thought. Thanks for the clarification.